# GAM (Google Admin): How to search query with empty custom field?

Tags: python, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

Hi I am working with GAM (Google-Admin-Manager) to manage our Google Workspace directory and have a custom field with bool value.

I need to print all users having this field empty (without a value).

`null`/`NULL` does not work...

`gam print users query "Non-Person_Account.Non-Person_Account=null"`

I also tried: empty, value, "", none; Always running into an error.

GAM is build with Python. Can someone help?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe display all values in field and see if it display it as `null`, `NULL`, `None`, `False`, etc.

Comment: if it is build with Python then you may try to digg in source code to see how it works. You could even add `print()` to display values in variables when you run code.